# Sum of independent random variables with linear coefficients

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

The problem can be stated like this: What is the distribution of all sums that can be made by summing a subset of the numbers $1,2,\dots, n$?

In other words we have $n$ independent binary random variables $B_j$ (indicator whether the number $j$ is taken to the sum) and we take their weighted sum

$$X=\sum_{j=1}^n j B_j $$

The question is what is the (normalized limiting) distribution of $X$? For warm-up let's calculate $\mathbb{E}[X] = \frac{n(n+1)}{4}$ and variance $\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{24}$. If we had just the sum, the central limit theorem would apply, but now when we have the linear coefficients $j$, is the resulting distribution still normal? The normal distribution with those parameters looks pretty close, but little bit too high in the center and little bit too low on the tails (and then again too high on the even further tails). If the standard deviation is increased, it fits better, but shouldn't the variances of the distributions agree if they are to approach each other? Or did I calculate the variance wrong? Now that I look at the tails even closer, the adjusted one is more off there. Maybe the distribution just isn't normal. I tried to calculate the characteristic function

$$\varphi_X (t) = \prod_{j=1}^n \left(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}e^{ijt}\right)$$

but I don't know where to go from there.

Here are Desmos's I have used to look at the distributions: [Desmos1](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ad2j3u1y06) and [Desmos2](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xfqaiuwmfm) (I calculated the distribution elsewhere for the second one to get it for bigger $n$).

**EDIT** For $k=50$: [Desmos3](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/jg1pmax6xl). Well, now it's pretty close. I assume it does converge to the normal distribution.

Comment: It should follow from [Lyapunov's CLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Lyapunov_CLT)

Comment: Most proofs of the central limit theorem (e.g. based on the characteristic function) generalize to this case without much difficulty. For the characteristic function you need to normalize appropriately and then take a Taylor series expansion of the logarithm in $t$.